# iOS AVFoundation/AVAudioRecorder Unknown crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

Apologies for the code dump, but i can't spot what is wrong.
The app is a basic record, pause, play using AVFoundation from this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-avfoundation-framework-tutorial/

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioRecorder.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *RecordButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *PlayButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *PauseButton;

- (IBAction)RecordButtonTapped:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)PlayButtonTapped:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PauseButtonTapped:(id)sender;


@end
```

**ViewController.M**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
    AVAudioPlayer *player;
}


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.PauseButton setEnabled:NO];
    [self.PlayButton setEnabled: NO];

    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject], @"MyAudio.m4a", nil];

    NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    //setup Audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    //define record settings

    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    //initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)RecordButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"RecordStart");
    if(player.playing){
        NSLog(@"Player stopped");
        [player stop];
    }

    if(!recorder.recording){
        NSLog(@"Not recording yet");
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setActive: YES error: nil];
        NSLog(@"Start session");
        //start recording
        [recorder record];
        NSLog(@"record");
        [self.RecordButton setAttributedTitle:(NSAttributedString *) @"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"title crap");

    } else{
        [recorder pause];
        NSLog(@"she be paused");
        [self.RecordButton setAttributedTitle:(NSAttributedString *) @"Record" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"she title crap");
    }
    [self.PauseButton setEnabled:YES];
    NSLog(@"pausebutton enabled");
    [self.PlayButton setEnabled:NO];
    NSLog(@"Play button not enabled");
}


- (IBAction)PlayButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if(!recorder.recording){
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player play];
    }
}

- (IBAction)PauseButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [recorder stop];
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setActive:NO error: nil];
}

-(void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    [self.RecordButton setAttributedTitle:(NSAttributedString *) @"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.PauseButton setEnabled:NO];
    [self.PlayButton setEnabled:YES];
}

-(void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" message:@"Finished Playing the recording!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
@end
```

**Console Output**

```
2014-11-14 12:12:14.495 AudioRecorder[1100:32446] RecordStart
2014-11-14 12:12:14.497 AudioRecorder[1100:32446] Not recording yet
2014-11-14 12:12:14.497 AudioRecorder[1100:32446] Start session
2014-11-14 12:12:14.498 AudioRecorder[1100:32446] record
2014-11-14 12:12:14.498 AudioRecorder[1100:32446] title crap
2014-11-14 12:12:14.498 AudioRecorder[1100:32446] pausebutton enabled
2014-11-14 12:12:14.499 AudioRecorder[1100:32446] Play button not enabled
2014-11-14 12:12:14.499 AudioRecorder[1100:32446] -[__NSCFConstantString _ui_synthesizeAttributedSubstringFromRange:usingDefaultAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101bee288
2014-11-14 12:12:14.505 AudioRecorder[1100:32446] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString _ui_synthesizeAttributedSubstringFromRange:usingDefaultAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101bee288'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102b81f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102471bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102b8904d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102ae127c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102ae0e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000103222293 -[UIButton _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 685
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001035ed9a1 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) intrinsicContentSize] + 37
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001035edea4 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _generateContentSizeConstraints] + 33
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001035edc64 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 422
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001035f50d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints] + 163
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000103221e20 -[UIButton updateConstraints] + 2925
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001035f46fa -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 248
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001035f48f2 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a8a194 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001035f469b -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 153
    15  Foundation                          0x0000000102017d6e -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 155
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001035f48f2 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001035f4dbe __60-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded]_block_invoke + 96
    18  Foundation                          0x0000000102017d6e -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 155
    19  UIKit                               0x00000001035f4a86 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 231
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001035f519e -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeeded] + 159
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000102fdbb2d -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 114
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000102fe7973 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    23  QuartzCore                          0x00000001053bcde8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    24  QuartzCore                          0x00000001053b1a0e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    25  QuartzCore                          0x00000001053b187e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    26  QuartzCore                          0x000000010531f63e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    27  QuartzCore                          0x000000010532074a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    28  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105320db5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102ab6dc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102ab6d20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102aacb53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102aac486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    33  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000105a5c9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    34  UIKit                               0x0000000102f6e420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    35  AudioRecorder                       0x0000000101beafd3 main + 115
    36  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010673f145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Try changing all of your `setAttributedTitle:(NSAttributedString *)` to `setTitle:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I've answered it as a comment above, I also put the modified code here, so you could just copy-pate if you would like.
I've just replaced all of your `setAttributedTitle:(NSAttributedString *)` with `setTitle:`

```
- (IBAction)RecordButtonTapped:(id)sender {  
    NSLog(@"RecordStart");  
    if(player.playing){  
        NSLog(@"Player stopped");  
        [player stop];  
    }  

    if(!recorder.recording){  
        NSLog(@"Not recording yet");  
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];  
        [session setActive: YES error: nil];  
        NSLog(@"Start session");  
        //start recording  
        [recorder record];  
        NSLog(@"record");  
        [self.RecordButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
        NSLog(@"title crap");  

    } else{  
        [recorder pause];  
        NSLog(@"she be paused");  
        [self.RecordButton setTitle:@"Record" forState: UIControlStateNormal];  
        NSLog(@"she title crap");  
    }  
    [self.PauseButton setEnabled:YES];  
    NSLog(@"pausebutton enabled");  
    [self.PlayButton setEnabled:NO];  
    NSLog(@"Play button not enabled");  
}  


-(void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag{  
    [self.RecordButton setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    [self.PauseButton setEnabled:NO];  
    [self.PlayButton setEnabled:YES];  
}
```

Comment: Ah! initial i did use `setTitle` but ran into errors that `setTitle` could not be found. clearly my mistake, thank you :)